# Redirect URL containing expression after domain name

Tags: regex, .htaccess

How do I express the following redirect rule using Regex and htaccess:

From:

```
domain.com/***anything***/itemlist/tag/***rest_of_URL
```

To:

```
domain.com/artigos/tag/***rest_of_URL
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
RewriteRule ^(*.)/itemlist/tag/(.*)$ /artigos/tag/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(*)/itemlist/tag/(.*)$ /artigos/tag/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/itemlist/tag/(.*)$ /artigos/tag/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(itemlist/tag)/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: It works perfectly thank you!
How about redirecting domain.com/***anything***/tag/***rest_of_URL I tried RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(tag)/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L,NC] but got a redirection cycle issue

Comment: Do you want to just remove `/tag/` from your URLs?

Comment: I'll open another question